# Existing SSIS Packages Suddenly fail to Validate custom components XML

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have been using and running SSIS packages for SQL Server 2014 with custom components that have been used since before I arrived at my work place. We upgraded to Visual Studio 2017, and have been fine doing so for months. Recently--maybe in line with a recent update--Visual Studio ssdt fails to load these packages because of errors regarding validating the xml behind these components. The packages continue to run on the server, and creating new packages with these custom components still works as expected. The packages also still open in Visual Studio 2013. We've gone back to earlier versions of the same package in code control. Reinstalled earlier versions of Visual Studio, installed the ssdt tools as a stand-alone, but nothing seems to work.

There is a slew or errors regarding being unable to load values that are part of the definition of these components, and bad references to these in the precedence constraints because of the failure to load these components in the first place, like:

`Error loading CCMI Call Import.dtsx: Error loading value "<DTS:ForEachEnumerator xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" DTS:CreationName="FolderEnumerator" DTS:DTSID="{FACFAC12-F5E1-4BFE-9768-BF73D8053550}" DTS:ObjectName="{FACFAC12-F5E1-4BFE-9768-BF73D8053550}"><DTS:PropertyExpression DTS:Name="Directory">@" from node "DTS:ForEachEnumerator".        C:\Users\..Call Import.dtsx 1`

When I remove all references to the custom components in the precedence constraints, it will attempt to load the package without the "corrupted" pieces, but because these custom components are containers, in some cases this leaves out most of the work that's been done. I've removed some of these "bad" values it can't load on a lark, but it keeps erroring on the next attribute still associated with the container after I remove the one previously referenced in the error.

I can't open the package, so I cant copy and paste the components into a new package.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did someone change the mode sql server runs in? If I remember correctly sql server can run in a later mode.

Comment: May not be related but we had issues when upgrading to Visual Studio 2017.  The issue was that the .net version in VS 2017 in the SSIS script tasks was a newer version then the one in our older SSIS script tasks so the build was not working because the .net versions were not compatable.  Just something to look into.

Comment: Just had something similar.  I first imported the packages from the server then later added the custom component/task to the SSIS toolbox.  Shoulda done it the other way 'round

Comment: These are all good places to go to, but the issue was that it was working for some months, still operating under SQL Server 2014. Opened it in 2013, where it still opens fine, copied the components into a new package, and **both** packages were working fine for a bit, but it reverted back to being broken and I can't replicate it--which is weird. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix some of the issues after some study of the XML of these custom components, and wanted to share in case it helped someone, although I doubt the exact same issues I came across would affect many other people.

I wasn't getting any useful error messages for a custom foreach loop container, but when I tried to copy it from a working VS 2013 screen into VS 2017, I did finally get an error stating something like (lost the exact quote) "missing attribute for the server target version". I then found that the working examples of the custom component that worked had this node that was missing from the XML that was "broken":

```
<TargetServerVersion
          Type="3"
          Value="120" />
```

I added the missing attribute and changed the value from 140 to 120 (the version we were actually targeting) and it began to work just fine.

Fixed another custom destination through a similar process, although the error was entirely different. In this scenario, the package would actually open without error, but the custom destination would not function properly (and also no longer had the custom icon). The working package I created with the custom component had an XML that was similar to the broken package's XML in this case. It wasn't until I created a new package in a new project where I immediately set the correct target server that I could see any change in the XML between the broken and working package's code, and it was this:

The 2017 version of the component had a much longer definition of the "UserComponentTypeName" property:

```
<properties>
            <property
              dataType="System.String"
              name="UserComponentTypeName">Konesans.Dts.Pipeline.TrashDestination.Trash, Konesans.Dts.Pipeline.TrashDestination, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b2ab4a111192992b</property>
          </properties>
```

The correct version for 2016 (I know, different from the last package) had a shorter, much simpler definition:

```
<properties>
            <property
              dataType="System.String"
              name="UserComponentTypeName">Konesans.TrashDestination</property>
          </properties>
```

It worked correctly when I replaced the property with the shorter definition.

I don't know how frequently these exact issues would come up, but I hadn't seen anything like this while searching for solutions to my problem and thought if someone had a different but related problem with XML changing (perhaps to someone accidentally upgrading a package version?) that it might help add a spark to the creative process and save some time.